# $_Post variable not saved in session

Tags: php, session

Novice programmer here.

I'm trying to save the value of a post variable in the PHP session, but the variables don't seem to get saved to the session.

I'm having trouble getting my head around the concept of post variables in relation to sessions so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something dumb that's very obvious but I can't seem to to figure out what. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code (some_page.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
if(isset($_POST['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['item_id'] = $_POST['item_id'];
}
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="some_page.php">
<input name="item_id" value="223">
<button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is called a [Logical Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error#Debugging_logic_errors). Read the section on debugging logical errors and try to debug yourself in the future as questions like these add very little overall value to StackOverflow.

Comment: You are checking if $_POST['cart_items'] is set. It's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a field with the name `cart_items` so

```
if(isset($_POST['cart_items']))
```

never evaluates as true.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names appear to be wrong:

```
if(isset($_POST['cart_items'])){ <-- here you have cart_items
    $_SESSION['item_id'] = $_POST['item_id']; <-- here you have item_id
}
```

I would imagine they should both be the same variable.